# how to install GD with freetype support for php in macOS 10.14.1 Mojave

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii-extensions, php-7.2

we are using with the yii2 framework and facing with captcha loading issue.

Trying to load captcha and getting below error.

Error:

> Invalid Configuration –
>   yii\base\InvalidConfigException
>   Either GD PHP extension with FreeType support or ImageMagick PHP
>   extension with PNG support is required.

While checking from yii2 vendor file we got with no value for FreeType Support. Could anyone provide with any reference URL or steps to resolve below?

```
Array
(
    [GD Version] => bundled (2.1.0 compatible)
    [FreeType Support] => 
    [GIF Read Support] => 1
    [GIF Create Support] => 1
    [JPEG Support] => 1
    [PNG Support] => 1
    [WBMP Support] => 1
    [XPM Support] => 
    [XBM Support] => 1
    [WebP Support] => 
    [JIS-mapped Japanese Font Support] => 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is not within Yii side. You don't have php extension which is required for captcha to work. Are you developing through virtual machine, vagrant, docker, xampp or something else? From that depends how you will install extension properly.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php or http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php

Example for this would be:
If you are running php from within linux machine:

`sudo apt-get install php-imagick` or `sudo apt-get install php-gd`

I think that you should have gd already installed but maybe you need to enable it ini `php.ini` config file. You have a lot of resources on that.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install php-gd` actually helped me